# Ruby sorting based on an if statement

Tags: ruby, sorting

I am trying to sort an array of words in Ruby 1.8.7 by an insane set of rules. This can be simplified to wanting to sort case-insensitive `.sort_by{|a| a.downcase}` then re-sort case-sensitive but only if the 2 strings are the same.

I would think you could just `.downcase` compare only the strings that are equal and then sort just those, sending 0 for the rest. But no, that isn't working for me.

Here's what I have:

```
["A", "a", "a.", "A.", "Ba", "ba"].sort_by{|a| a.downcase}.sort{|a,b| a.downcase==b.downcase ? a<=>b : 0 }
```

Desired output:

```
["A", "a", "A.", "a.", "Ba", "ba"]
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `a.downcase == b.downcase` then you want to sort using a case-sensitive comparison, right? That really means that you want to sort by the pair `[a.downcase, a]` and arrays in Ruby compare element by element so you just want:

```
array.sort_by { |s| [ s.downcase, s ] }
```

Suppose `sort_by` is comparing two arrays `a1` and `a2` to see which one goes first. That's just an `a1 <=> a2` call. If `a1[0] != a2[0]` then the spaceship operator won't have to look at the second elements of the arrays to break a tie because there is no tie and `<=>` can return `+1` or `-1` right away. If `a1[0] == a2[0]` then `a1[0] <=> a2[0]` is `0` and the spaceship has to look at the second elements to see how to break the tie (or leave the tie as-is if `a1 == a2`). That sounds like the comparison logic you're after.

Comment: Where  says " ...and arrays in Ruby compare element by element..." that is explained more fully in the doc for [Arrays#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-3C-3D-3E). To carry this one step further, If you (the OP) wanted to sort first on `s` downcased, then sort ties on the length of `s`, longest first, then sort ties of both `s.downcase` and `s.size` by `s`, you could sort on the array `[s.downcase, -s.size, s]`.

Comment: Using an array to sort by multiple conditions is an idea I hadn't seen before. This is very helpful.

Comment: This is a great answer to the question. Exactly the answer I needed for the question I posed, so thank you. I have to add that I'm torn because I posted this to try to fix my `a.downcase==b.downcase` approach, instead your answer made me perfectly rethink my question in the way I needed to get the job done, so I will happily give you the checkmark. Unfortunately, now this question feels like a duplicate to all these: https://www.google.com/#q=ruby+sort+by+multiple+site:stackoverflow.com and for that I apologize to anyone who eventually marks this question as a duplicate.